# Authorize.net - GetHostedPaymentPageRequest class not found

Tags: php, authorize.net

I'm attempting to integrate a [hosted payment page](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/accept_hosted.html) using Authorize.Net

I have successfully installed the SDK using Composer (including dependencies) and got the [Hello World](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/) example working.

However, when trying to create a hosted payment page using the [sample code](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/get-an-accept-payment-page.php) provided, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'net\authorize\api\contract\v1\GetHostedPaymentPageRequest' not found
```

I'm guessing this is some namespace issue, but I can't trace it. Changing the class name key as per this [issue](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/211) on GitHib seems to have no effect.

Comment: Experiencing the same error.  Cannot find a fix to date.  Have you?

Comment: Sorry, no - I wrote my own solution. You can post an array to `https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment` with the following [elements](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions-get-an-accept-payment-page). You may also have to remove BOM characters from JSON response.